# How to group data (on SQL server) based positive and negative column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table ->

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id |  gainOnX  |  gainOnY  |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |        10 |        10 |
|  1 |        -5 |         5 |
|  2 |        -5 |       -10 |
|  2 |       -10 |         5 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to group this data by id, but i need 4 columns

1. sum of positive x (total profit on x)
2. sum of negative x (total loss on x)
3. sum of positive y (total profit on y)
4. sum of negative y (total loss on y)

So it should look something like this ->

```
+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
| id | profitX | lossX | profitY | lossY |
+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
|  1 |      10 |    -5 |      15 |     0 |
|  2 |       0 |   -15 |       5 |   -10 |
+----+---------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when gainOnX > 0 then gainOnX else 0 end),
       sum(case when gainOnX < 0 then gainOnX else 0 end),
       sum(case when gainOnY > 0 then gainOnY else 0 end),
       sum(case when gainOnY < 0 then gainOnY else 0 end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: WOW ! what an elegant solution, thank you so much. I was about to create 4 tables and take their join, lol !

Comment: "Conditional aggregation" is better known as a "CROSSTAB".  It's similar to PIVOT but CROSSTABs are usually faster and easier to control,.